# Candlestick chart in Python X-Axis appears crammed

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am running code from the following website :

https://ntguardian.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/stock-data-analysis-python-v2/

which generates a candle chart. I have run similar code in Spyder and the only amendments I have made to the code are

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,DayLocator,MONDAY
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
```

Their chart looks like this on the webpage:
[image: Their chart looks like this on the webpage]

This is my chart when I run it in Spyder
[image: This is my chart when I run it in Spyder]

I can't seem to understand why when I haven't altered the code why I would see such a stark difference.

Is there some quirk in Spyder that creates this proble or do I need to have a few more lines of code?

Please help me with this as I am new to matplotlib.

Thanks a lot and really appreciate your help with this.

My overall code

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
 pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
 pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)



 import quandl
 import datetime

 # We will look at stock prices over the past year, starting at January 

 start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
 end =datetime.date.today()

 #Fist define the security for which you are extracting the Series
 s = "AAPL"
 apple = quandl.get("WIKI/" + s, start_date=start, end_date=end)

 print (type(apple))

 print (apple.head())

 #print (apple.tail())

 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pylab

 #Lines of Code for Jupyter
 # This line is necessary for the plot to appear in a Jupyter notebook
 #%matplotlib inline
 # Control the default size of figures in this Jupyter notebook
 #%pylab inline


 pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 9)  # Change the size of plots

 print (apple["Adj. Close"].plot(grid = True))

 from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, 
 MONDAY
 from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
 from matplotlib.dates import date2num


 def pandas_candlestick_ohlc(dat, stick = "day", adj = False, otherseries = 
     None):
"""
:param dat: pandas DataFrame object with datetime64 index, and float columns 
"Open", "High", "Low", and "Close", likely created via DataReader from 
"yahoo"
:param stick: A string or number indicating the period of time covered by a 
single candlestick. Valid string inputs include "day", "week", "month", and 
"year", ("day" default), and any numeric input indicates the number of 
 trading days included in a period
:param adj: A boolean indicating whether to use adjusted prices
:param otherseries: An iterable that will be coerced into a list, containing 
the columns of dat that hold other series to be plotted as lines

This will show a Japanese candlestick plot for stock data stored in dat, 
also plotting other series if passed.
"""
mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

# Create a new DataFrame which includes OHLC data for each period specified 
by stick input
fields = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"]
if adj:
    fields = ["Adj. " + s for s in fields]
transdat = dat.loc[:,fields]
transdat.columns = pd.Index(["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"])
if (type(stick) == str):
    if stick == "day":
        plotdat = transdat
        stick = 1 # Used for plotting
    elif stick in ["week", "month", "year"]:
        if stick == "week":
            transdat["week"] = pd.to_datetime(transdat.index).map(lambda x: 
    x.isocalendar()[1]) # Identify weeks
        elif stick == "month":
            transdat["month"] = pd.to_datetime(transdat.index).map(lambda x: 
    x.month) # Identify months
        transdat["year"] = pd.to_datetime(transdat.index).map(lambda x: 
    x.isocalendar()[0]) # Identify years
        grouped = transdat.groupby(list(set(["year",stick]))) # Group by 
    year and other appropriate variable
        plotdat = pd.DataFrame({"Open": [], "High": [], "Low": [], "Close": 
    []}) # Create empty data frame containing what will be plotted
        for name, group in grouped:
            plotdat = plotdat.append(pd.DataFrame({"Open": group.iloc[0,0],
                                        "High": max(group.High),
                                        "Low": min(group.Low),
                                        "Close": group.iloc[-1,3]},
                                       index = [group.index[0]]))
        if stick == "week": stick = 5
        elif stick == "month": stick = 30
        elif stick == "year": stick = 365

  elif (type(stick) == int and stick >= 1):
    transdat["stick"] = [np.floor(i / stick) for i in 
  range(len(transdat.index))]
    grouped = transdat.groupby("stick")
    plotdat = pd.DataFrame({"Open": [], "High": [], "Low": [], "Close": []}) 
# Create empty data frame containing what will be plotted
    for name, group in grouped:
        plotdat = plotdat.append(pd.DataFrame({"Open": group.iloc[0,0],
                                    "High": max(group.High),
                                    "Low": min(group.Low),
                                    "Close": group.iloc[-1,3]},
                                   index = [group.index[0]]))

else:
    raise ValueError('Valid inputs to argument "stick" include the strings "day", "week", "month", "year", or a positive integer')


# Set plot parameters, including the axis object ax used for plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
if plotdat.index[-1] - plotdat.index[0] < pd.Timedelta('730 days'):
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
else:
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d, %Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

ax.grid(True)

# Create the candelstick chart
candlestick_ohlc(ax, list(zip(list(date2num(plotdat.index.tolist())), 
plotdat["Open"].tolist(), plotdat["High"].tolist(),
                  plotdat["Low"].tolist(), plotdat["Close"].tolist())),
                  colorup = "black", colordown = "red", width = stick * .4)

# Plot other series (such as moving averages) as lines
if otherseries != None:
    if type(otherseries) != list:
        otherseries = [otherseries]
    dat.loc[:,otherseries].plot(ax = ax, lw = 1.3, grid = True)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, 
horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()

pandas_candlestick_ohlc(apple, adj=True, stick="month")
```

Comment: If you run the _exact_ same code they are do you get the same result that the article does? If not then you might be using different versions of the various libraries..

Comment: I use the exact same code that generates the candlestick chart

Comment: I can't seem to understand why the x-axis is so crammed for me. Thank you @DavidG for trying to help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a [mcve] i.e. a piece of code we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello @DavidG. I have put what I could . I know it does not appear minimal but I didn't know how to shorted it further because I am clueless about what is causing the problem and have put my code. I apologize if this is not brief.

Comment: Note that the code uses the current date, `datetime.date.today()`, so running it at different times, *may*  lead to different results. To be sure to see the same image as on the website you would need to replace the `end` date with the date on which the website has been made (not sure if that date is known though).

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but the dates are still crammed. I think date must be after March 2018 from the chart on the web but when I try it, it still looks crammed.

Comment: So the difference results from the line `if plotdat.index[-1] - plotdat.index[0] < pd.Timedelta('730 days'):` This is apparently True for you, but was False when the plot on the website was created.

Comment: Ah! I see I will alter the line of code and see what I get.

Comment: But the interval of the chart (X Axis) appears to be days and not eevry three months like on the website.

Comment: If you arrive in the `else` clause, it will be automatic (hence some 10 intervals along the axis). If you arrive in the `if` clause, it will be set to days.

Comment: So what should I change it to? %m?? Maybe

Comment: You can simply remove the if/else and only keep what's inside `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to understand this but after re-copying the code and shutting down Spyder and re-starting, it appears to work now. Thank you to @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest and @DavidG for helping me with this.